# context of `this` in javascript react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am following the `react-navigation` [navigator tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/) here and get confused with the way `this.navigator` is set using `this.navigator = nav`

The full code is as below:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(SomeAppRouteConfigs);

class App extends React.Component {
  someEvent() {
    // call navigate for AppNavigator here:
    this.navigator && this.navigator.dispatch(
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: someRouteName })
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }} />
    );
  }
}
```

From my understanding (at least with programming languages other than JavaScript, the `this` in `<AppNavigator ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }} />` should be referring to `AppNavigator`, thus, how can the code in `someEvent` seems like accessing the same `this.navigator` set by that code?

Any clue will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not bind its own this

[from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Therefore `this` is bound to `App` which explains the behaviour.